# Deploy Angular-8 APP in unknown sub folder

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I need to deploy my Angular-8 App in a folder like this:

> http://server-url/some-unknown-folder/app

like

> http://localhost/folder/app/

when i specify --base-href /app/ the application can not find the css/js files

I don't know the **folder** when my app will be installed

the angular APP should be "self contained"

When i build like this

"npm run build -- --prod --aot --deploy-url /folder/app/"

I have 2 problems:

1. as said above, i don't know the "folder" where it will be installed
2. calls to API located in parent location (http://localhost/folder/api/) fails since the app tries to access http://localhost/api and not http://localhost/folder/api

Ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the parameter `baseHref` when building, like this `ng build --prod --aot --baseHref /folder/app/`. If you need to update this parameter, and you can't do a new build, then you can change it in the `index.html` file. It is located in the `<head>` section, `<base>` tag.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know the "folder" path. The client may install it where ever he want without me being able to know it

Comment: The proposed solution was as part of the deploy process. At the moment your client decide where to put the app, he only need to change that parameter of the dist folder you gave him.

Comment: If the question is, how to build the app so it can be deploy in any path and without doing any modification after the build?, I don't know the answer sorry.

Comment: Yes, The client is not technical , he can not modify html files